# How to remove all elements after specific list value?

Tags: javascript

I have a list -

```html
<ol>
<li>Value 1</li>
<li>Value 2</li>
<li>Value 3</li>
<li>Value 4</li>
<li>Value 5</li>
</ol>
```

How do I remove all list values after the user has clicked a specific value, ex: If the user has clicked `Value 3`, I want to be able to keep `Value 1, Values 2 and Value 3` and removed the rest. I have tried `findIndex()` to find the index position of clicked list and then `splice()` the list since lists also have indexes but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Loop over each `li` and bind click event. Inside click event get clicked `li` with `this`. We can get next element with `nextElementSibling`. So loop unitl next element sibling is available & remove it.

Try it below.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(x => x.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let li = this;
  // loop unitl next element sibling is available.
  while (li.nextElementSibling) {
    // remove next element
    li.nextElementSibling.remove();
  }
}))
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Value 1</li>
  <li>Value 2</li>
  <li>Value 3</li>
  <li>Value 4</li>
  <li>Value 5</li>
</ol>
```

---

**Edit** As suggested from [@mplungjan in comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65609038/how-to-remove-all-elements-after-specific-list-value/65609413#comment115999468_65609413) you can also delegate event from `ol` like below. Define `click` event on `ol` and then verify if `e.target` is `li` with condition `e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'li'`. Get clicked `li` with `e.target`. Remaining logic will be same as above.

```js
document.querySelector('ol').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'li') {
    let li = e.target;
    // loop unitl next element sibling is available.
    while (li.nextElementSibling) {
      // remove next element
      li.nextElementSibling.remove();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Value 1</li>
  <li>Value 2</li>
  <li>Value 3</li>
  <li>Value 4</li>
  <li>Value 5</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Why not delegate from OL?

Comment: @mplungjan, Updated answer and added solution with delegate from `ol` as well.

Comment: The combination of delegating from OL (which cuts the number of eventlisteners considerably) and using nextElementSibling is the neatest answer so far.

Comment: PS: The last example is identical to [Tal's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65609419/295783)

Comment: @AHaworth [Mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65609302/295783) can handle markup in the lI

Answer (score 1):

You can find index manually like this

```js
const list = document.querySelectorAll('li');

list.forEach(x => x.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var i = 0;
  for (; list[i] != this; i++) {}
  for (i = i + 1; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i].remove();
  }
}))
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Value 1</li>
  <li>Value 2</li>
  <li>Value 3</li>
  <li>Value 4</li>
  <li>Value 5</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Why not delegate from the ol?

Comment: At least cache the LIs (I updated your code for you)

Answer (score 1):

Delegate and remove lastChild until element met

***NOTE*** this code can handle child tags in the LI

```js
const ol = document.querySelector('ol');
ol.addEventListener('click', ({target}) => {
  target = target.closest('LI'); // can handle LI child tags
  while (ol.lastChild !== target)
    ol.lastChild.remove();
});
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Value 1</li>
  <li>Value 2</li>
  <li><b>Value 3</b></li>
  <li>Value 4</li>
  <li>Value 5</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is dynamic event listener, which means that no matter how many element will be inside your `ol` list it would always work

```js
const $listContainerOBJ = document.getElementById('listContainer');

$listContainerOBJ.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (target.nodeName === 'LI') {
    while (target.nextElementSibling) {
      target.nextElementSibling.remove();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<ol id="listContainer">
<li>Value 1</li>
<li>Value 2</li>
<li>Value 3</li>
<li>Value 4</li>
<li>Value 5</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: @mplungjan Note that if your code would have HTML such that there are text-equal elements : `<li>v1</li><li>v1</li>` it would not work

Comment: Ah, you are correct. Now my code is even more elegant ;)

Comment: And now your code is almost identical to mine ;)

Comment: See my [update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65609302/295783) to handle markup in the LI

Answer (score 1):

This is a more dynamic approach but you may find it clearer to use if it fits your project. It keeps a full list of the items in an array and repopulates the list on every click, based on the click index. It works multiple times. Until of course all the items are gone.

```js
const listElement = document.getElementById('list')

const listEntries = [
  'Value 1',
  'Value 2',
  'Value 3',
  'Value 4',
  'Value 5'  
];

const repopulateList = () => {
  listElement.innerHTML = '';
  listEntries.forEach((entry, index) => {
    if (index > lastClicked) {
      return false;
    }
    let listItem = null;
    listItem = document.createElement('li');
    listItem.innerHTML = entry;
    listItem.addEventListener('click', () => { handleListItemClick(index); });
    listElement.appendChild(listItem);
  });  
}

let lastClicked = listEntries.length + 1;

const handleListItemClick = (index) => {
  lastClicked = index;
  repopulateList();  
}

repopulateList()
```

```html
<ol id="list"></ol>
```

Comment: You can create a snippet here too using the `[<>]` snippet editor